# F#: Tell me what I'm missing about using Async.Parallel

Tags: f#, parallel-processing

ok, so I'm doing ProjectEuler Problem #14, and I'm fiddling around with optimizations in order to feel f# out.

in the following code:

```
let evenrule n = n / 2L
let oddrule n = 3L * n + 1L

let applyRule n =
    if n % 2L = 0L then evenrule n
    else oddrule n

let runRules n =
    let rec loop a final =
        if a = 1L then final
        else loop (applyRule a) (final + 1L)
    n, loop (int64 n) 1L


let testlist = seq {for i in 3 .. 2 .. 1000000 do yield i } 

let getAns sq = sq |> Seq.head

let seqfil (a,acc) (b,curr) = if acc = curr then (a,acc) else if acc < curr then (b,curr) else (a,acc)

let pmap f l = 
    seq { for a in l do yield async {return f a} }
    |> Seq.map Async.RunSynchronously

let pmap2 f l = 
    seq { for a in l do yield async {return f a} }
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously

let procseq f l = l
                  |> f runRules
                  |> Seq.reduce seqfil
                  |> fst

let timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
timer.Start()
let ans1 = testlist |> procseq Seq.map // 837799    00:00:08.6251990
printfn "%A\t%A" ans1 timer.Elapsed
timer.Reset()

timer.Start()
let ans2 = testlist |> procseq pmap
printfn "%A\t%A" ans2 timer.Elapsed // 837799   00:00:12.3010250
timer.Reset()

timer.Start()
let ans3 = testlist |> procseq pmap2
printfn "%A\t%A" ans3 timer.Elapsed // 837799   00:00:58.2413990
timer.Reset()
```

Why does the Async.Parallel code run REALLY slow in comparison to the straight up map?  I know I shouldn't see that much of an effect, since I'm only on a dual core mac.

Please note that I do NOT want help solving problem #14, I just want to know what's up with my parallel code.

Comment: Why do it in parallel then do it synchronously? Your piping seems odd.

Comment: Because I don't know how to get the values? 

I was under the impression that Async.Parallel gives you a list set up to be processed in parallel, and then Async.RunSynchronously runs the Async.Parallel-ized sequence and waits for it to finish (but it's processed in parallel)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The use of `Async.Parallel` seems to be correct. The numbers really look suspicious, but I don't immediately see what may be a problem here.

In any case, asynchronous workflows are really more suitable for computations that involve some *asynchronous* operation (such as I/O, communication, waiting for events, etc.). For CPU intensive tasks, it is better to use Parallel Extensions to .NET (which are now a part of .NET 4.0; unfortunatelly there is no .NET 2.0 version).

To do that from F#, you'll need [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) and the `FSharp.PowerPack.Parallel.Seq.dll` assembly, which contains parallel versions of higher-order functions for working with sequences (such as `map` :-))

These functions return a value of type `pseq<'a>` (called `ParallelQuery<T>` in C#), which represent a delayed computation running in parallel (this enables better optimizations when you use multiple operations in pipeline). There is also `PSeq.reduce` function, so you may want to use this in your processing too (aside from `PSeq.map`).

Comment: Curses! This limits experiments with Parallel Extensions to my PC. Hurry up, mono! Get us up to 4.0!

Comment: It looks like Mono folks are certainly interested in Parallel Extensions http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Jul-26-1.html, but I'm not sure about the current status... I wrote an implementation of `PSeq.map` and `PSeq.filter` myself some time ago (http://tomasp.net/blog/fsparallelops.aspx), but the performance is probably not the best...

Comment: There is a version of the Parallel Extensions for .NET 2.0. It ships as part of the Reactive Extensions.

Answer (score 3):

On my box, it takes about half a second to run the non-async one.  Since there are about a half a million work items here, that means each one runs in about 1 microsecond on average.

These items are too small to try to parallelize individually.  The overhead of doing the thread-scheduling and synchronization will dominate the actual work.  You need to choose better granularity.

(I'll work on some quick code...)

EDIT:

Ok, the code as-is is not too easy to re-do to change the batch granularity without some major rewriting, so I don't have new code to share that doesn't give too much away.  But I was able to make it run nearly twice as fast on my 2-core box by making batches of 50,000 elements each and doing the "map reduce" on each batch and a "parallel-map reduce" on the 10 or so batches.

See also

http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2008/08/12/8849984.aspx

especially the "task granularity" section.

Comment: This article helped open my eyes a little more. I encourage everyone else to read it too!

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know what's up with my parallel code

Heh, what isn't wrong with your parallel code. ;-)

Here's how I'd solve the problem:

```
  let rec inside (a : _ array) n =
    if n <= 1L || a.[int n] > 0s then a.[int n] else
      let p =
        if n &&& 1L = 0L then inside a (n >>> 1) else
          let n = 3L*n + 1L
          if n < int64 a.Length then inside a n else outside a n
      a.[int n] <- 1s + p
      1s + p
  and outside (a : _ array) n =
    let n = if n &&& 1L = 0L then n >>> 1 else 3L*n + 1L
    1s + if n < int64 a.Length then inside a n else outside a n

  let euler14 n =
    let a = Array.create (n+1) 0s
    let a = Array.Parallel.init (n+1) (fun n -> inside a (int64 n))
    let i = Array.findIndex (Array.reduce max a |> (=)) a
    i, a.[i]
```

This program uses speculative parallelism with a safe race condition and achieves a modest 2× speedup on my 8 cores.